# Incorrect conversion value for CGSize/SizeF binding

Tags: xamarin.ios, gmgridview

I'm working on MonoTouch binding project to integrate [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) into my application.  I was able to successfully load the empty Grid view but was not able to load grid items.  After spending hours on MonoTouch & Objective C code, it turned out that System.Drawing.SizeF binding is incorrectly translating to CGSize (i.e, SizeF(140f, 110f) is translating to CGSize(140, 0) - value of height is lost).

Objective C Definition

```
    - (CGSize)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
```

Monotouch Binding

```
    [Abstract, Export ("GMGridView:sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:")]
    System.Drawing.SizeF SizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation (GMGridView gridView, UIInterfaceOrientation orientation);
```

I was wondering if I'm [binding](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) it incorrectly or this is a known bug? Also, what would be a resolution other than creating additional callback for height value.

Binding and test code is posted here: [GMGridMono](https://github.com/rpulipati/GMGridMono)

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Great idea, MonoTouch really lacks a Grid View component. I'll try to help you with the port as soon as I have some time.

Comment: Sure, feel free to update the project.  For now, I'm creating an additional callback to pass height.

Comment: Which version of MonoTouch are you using and does this happen in the simulator or on device (or both)? I just tried with 5.2.11 and I couldn't find any problems in the simulator (I printed out the return value from SizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation in SlidesGridView.cs:29, and they're fine).

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Thanks for looking into it.  It is happening in the simulator. I havent tested with the device.  I'll test and update the post.

Comment: I see this project has been discontinued :( https://github.com/rpulipati/GMGridMono

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue with bindings to a method returning CGSize. Monotouch V5.2.12. It happens on the simulator but not on the device. A direct call from a mono application to the method works fine, but when the method is used as a callback from the bound library to the mono code the returned Height value is incorrect and appears ininitialized.